# Ionic project localStorage stops to work after adding crosswalk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I have an ionic project that uses `localStorage`, is working for months but after I added crosswalk the `localStorage` is not working anymore. The strange thing is, I create another app with `ionic start todo-list sidemenu` and created a simple todo-list using `localStorage` and worked.

Probably the issue is with something in my another app combined with crosswalk that is conflicting and ruining the `localStorage`.

I know what I said is to vague but maybe someone could had this same issue.

At [this link](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview#drawbacks):

> Crosswalk WebView stores data (IndexedDB, LocalStorage, etc) separately from System WebView

I'm using like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
window.localStorage.getItem('foo');
```

**The example above, the `getItem` will display the `bar` value but if I close the app and do `getItem('foo')` in another part of the app the value return `null`.**

**The issue is just happening on Android devices (tested 4.1, 4.3 and 4.4), at web browser is working.**

For the record, that is the plugins installed at the project:

```
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.4.0 "PushPlugin"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 1.1.0 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
nl.x-services.plugins.toast 2.0.5 "Toast"
```

Comment: When you say that localStorage doesn't work any more you mean that your old data disappeared? If you have old data saved in System Webview localStorage it is normal that those data disappears when you use Crosswalk WebView, as the link you posted states.

Comment: localStorage is a browser feature and has nothing to do with any cordova plugin. But, it may so happen that the key used by you and some other plugin turns out to be the same one..

Comment: @baxeico not old data, after crosswalk added if I do `setItem('foo', 'bar')` close the app and try `getItem('foo')` it returns `null`. If I do `setItem('foo', 'bar')` and bellow `getItem('foo')` I have the `bar` value. I made a little update in the question

Comment: Strange. I suggest to remote debug your app following [this tutorial](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/remote_debugging.html). In dev tools under "Resources" you can find localStorage data. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (using cordova-android 4.0 and Crosswalk 13.42.319.11). Before adding Crosswalk, localStorage worked as expected. After adding Crosswalk, any new items added to local storage would not be persisted if the application unloaded and restarted.

Through a process of elimination I found the following code in our application that appeared to trigger the problem:

```
// The purpose of this code is to check whether Safari browser is in "Private" browsing mode,
// in which case the localStorage API is available but throws an exception when setItem() is called:
// "QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota."

function testLocalStorageIsSupported() {
    try {
        if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage.setItem && window.localStorage.getItem && window.localStorage.removeItem) {
            // Store an arbitrary value
            var storedValue = (new Date().valueOf()).toString();
            window.localStorage.setItem("__LocalStorageIsSupported__", storedValue);

            var loadedValue = window.localStorage.getItem("__LocalStorageIsSupported__");
            window.localStorage.removeItem("__LocalStorageIsSupported__");

            // If loaded value matches the stored value then consider localStorage to be supported.
            return (storedValue == loadedValue);
        }

        return false;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("LocalStorage: Caught an error testing availability of localstorage: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code was being called after the deviceready event is received. Removing this code from the application solved the problem for me.

I reduced the problem code to the one line:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("__LocalStorageIsSupported__", (new Date().valueOf()).toString())
```

I did some further testing, by creating a blank cordova-android 4.0 application, and adding Crosswalk. Initially localStorage works as it should. After adding the above single line of code into the callback for the deviceready event, localStorage stopped persisting.

Comment: What you said is exactly what is happening with me but I can't understand what in your code id triggering the issue, is the `date`?

Comment: Ok I got the code, do you think the date format stored is the issue? What you did to resolve it?

Comment: It was simply the fact of calling `localStorage.setItem()` soon after the app started (so nothing to do with what data was actually being stored - be it a date or anything else). I suspect it's a timing sensitive issue - i.e. a certain length of time before which it seems it isn't safe to call `localStorage.setItem()` but after that time has elapsed it seems to be okay. I resolved it by removing the `localStorage.setItem()` call in the app startup code. I suggest you step through your code to find any instances of where `localStorage.setItem()` is called soon or very soon after your app starts

Comment: make sense.. probably the localStorage is not ready so it returns null. Theres some event like `webview.ready` or something like that? Maybe it could solve the issue.

Comment: I tested here and don't works. I access the localStorage as soon as the app starts, I dont use any setItem but getItem and I thought I was trying to getItem too soon and it was `null` but I put a timeout with 3 seconds before getItem and the issue still